# mysql: select all notified persons

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have notifications table and agent table. In notification table there is a alert_persons (ENUM: `AGENT, SALES, ADMIN, ALL`).

My query runs perfect in particular selection of `AGENT` or `SALES`.

But, If there is an ALL option selected then I want to show that notification to `AGENT`, `SALES` and `ADMIN`.

Here is my query.

```
SELECT *
FROM notification n
JOIN agent a ON n.author_id = a.id
AND type_id =1
AND n.type = 'CLIENT'
AND CASE WHEN (
alert_persons = 'ALL'
)
THEN 1
END
```

Here, type = notification category. id = notification category's id
But, I am not getting the correct result.

EDIT:
Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/318b3/1

Comment: How is an entry in the agent table labeled as AGENT, SALES, or ADMIN?  Is there a column in that table with the same enum values?

Comment: Please post a schema, and sample data - ideally as a sqlfiddle.

Comment: How do you pass in the selection (i.e. ALL vs AGENT)?  The problem is that ALL is a unique value, very different from AGENT,SALES, and ADMIN.

Comment: I have updated my question with sqlfiddle schema.. Thanks..

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: if alert_persons = 'ALL', then I need that notification to each category(CLIENT, AGENT, ADMIN, SUPERVISOR, SALES). And notification related to that other options in alert_persons

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a variable called **@NOTIFY** and it can be

***'ALL','AGENT','SALES', or 'ADMIN'***

Try the following

```
SELECT *
FROM notification n
JOIN agent a ON n.author_id = a.id
AND type_id =1
AND n.type = 'CLIENT'
AND CASE WHEN (
   @Notify = 'ALL' OR alert_persons = @Notify
)
THEN 1
END
Where, type = notification category. id = notification category's id
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/318b3/4

Comment: I have updated my question qith sqlfiddle link.. Can you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it:

```
SELECT *
FROM notification n
JOIN agent a ON n.author_id = a.id
AND type_id =1
AND n.type = 'CLIENT'
AND CASE WHEN (
  alert_persons = 'CLIENT'
)
THEN alert_persons = 'CLIENT'
WHEN (
  alert_persons = 'ALL'
)
THEN 1
END
```